# Connecting Rails api association with Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ember-data, ruby-on-rails-5

I've two models: `user` and `card`.

When a user creates a new card, I want to associate the user with that card. (You can assume that the `user_id` is 1)

For the Rails part,

**card.rb**

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cards
end
```

For the Ember part,

**app/routes/card/new.js**

```
  actions: {
    save(title, description) {
      let user = this.get('store').find('user', 1);

      const newCard = this.get('store').createRecord('card', {
        title,
        description,
        user
      });
      newCard.save().then((card) => {
        // go to the new item's route after creating it.
        this.transitionTo('card.card', card);
      });
    }
  }
```

Currently, I can associate them through the Rails console. I want to know how I can associate both of them through the Rails api and Ember data so that when I create a new `card`, it associates the `current user` along with that `card`.

Repo link (Rails): https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-server

Repo link (Ember): https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the code in your controller:

https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-server/blob/master/app/controllers/cards_controller.rb

In your `create` method you need to take the user id you receive and make the connection.

#### EDIT:

```
def create
  @card = Card.new(card_params)

  if @card.save
    @card.users << User.find(params[:data][:attributes][:user_id]) if params[:data][:attributes][:user_id] # this is my guess
    render json: @card
  else
    render json: @card, :status => 422
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry for being a newbie question but any idea how can i connect that?

Comment: I updated with some code. It might not be the exact correct location for your user id in the params. Rails does some stuff under the hood here. the `<<` actually creates an entry in the database map table `user_cards` (or `card_users`). This is why it has do be done after the save.